# how to run testng test cases jar with all dependence?

Tags: java, jar, testng

I use Intelli J IDE to build one executable JAR which contains all dependencies and test classes.

the /src/main/java/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF is

> Manifest-Version: 1.0 Main-Class: org.testng.TestNG

When I run the jar with the command

> java -jar tahoe-test.jar org.testng.TestNG suites/t123.xml

I get error:

> Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile tahoe-test.jar

If I unzip the jar and then run the command

> java org.testng.TestNG suites/t123.xml

all works fine! Why cant I run the jar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try run:

```
java -cp tahoe-test.jar org.testng.TestNG suites/t123.xml
```

Comment: Sorry, it still not works. Show: `Error: Could not find or load main class org.testng.TestNG`

Comment: After use maven-shade-plugin rebuild the jar. It works now. Thanks!

Comment: I suspected your Jar hasn't been created properly. Anyway, I was happy to help.